# click twice to open modal and not close

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap, angular11

I got this error when I open modal using double click and close it. I'm using

```
"ngb-modal": "^2.0.3"
```

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
> Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Note: When I use single click for close it working fine.

Modal Open

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.myModal, {
      size: size,
      modalClass: "mymodal",
      hideCloseButton: true,
      centered: false,
      backdrop: true,
      animation: true,
      keyboard: false,
      closeOnOutsideClick: false,
      backdropClass: "modal-backdrop",
    });
```

Modal Close

```
this.modalService.close(this.modalRef)
```

Comment: please provide an stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad, if you try to get the response in a close modal in ngb-modal don't forget use the "error" in Promise (the second one parameter of the promise)

```
this.modalService.open(content, ).result.then(
    (result) => {
      //so something
    },
    (error) => { //<--you should include this
      //do nothing, left empty if you want
    });
```